# How can I represent the first order logic statement "nobody is a mother of themself".?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

How can I represent the first order logic statement "nobody is a mother of themself".?
Not sure if the quantifiers/logic is correct, but my guess would be:

```
all x all y ((MotherOf(x, y) AND -MotherOf(y, x)).
```

Comment: This would mean everyone is a mother of everyone else, and also, no one is a mother of anyone.

Comment: actually I don't need to use `y`, right? perhaps this would work? `all x (-MotherOf(x, x)).`

Comment: Much better, you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final answer for this question as:
`all x (-MotherOf(x, x)).`

It means that nobody can be mother of themself.